# What is the story of the cowherd who died of shock after Shrinivasa's Darshan?

Tags: vishnu, venkateshwara

In story of Srinivasa/[Venkateswara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara),a Cowherd loses prana by the shocking Darshan of Shriman Narayana. The cowherd must be very lucky man to have died after having darshan of Shriman Narayana and he must have been granted moksha. So what is the past of the Cowherd, did he attain moksha after that birth. Why was the jiva inside the body of cowherd chosen for this task?

Comment: I don't know anything about the cowherd's past births, but yes he did attain Moksha.  Also, to this day the descendants of the cowherd are given the honor of getting first Darshan of Venkateshwara every day.  The family is called the Sannidhi Gollas.  Every morning, the Sannidhi Golla opens the doors of the Garbagraha (sanctum sanctorum) of the Tirupati temple.  It's only after the Sannidhi Golla has seen Venkateshwara that the priests can see him.

Comment: Golla is a Caste in Andhra who rear cattle and "sannidhi" is Proximity. Yeah, they do open doors for the first time every day. Majority of Golla people in Andhra worship Venkateswara as their Kula Diavam.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Sannidhi in this context means shrine, not proximity.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I just came to know from [Andhra Bharati Dictionary](http://www.andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php) that in *vaishnava Dialect* sannidhi also means Shrine.